# What is this table format called?

Tags: layout, tables, data-tables

What would you call this type of table row layout?

(This is from Mailchimp's email campaign manager section.)

[image]

It's not a traditional data table, since it combines about 6 pieces of information in the left column, instead of using a separate column for each (title, type, audience, segment, date sent, etc).

Also, any thoughts on the usability of this type of pattern? I personally like it because the search bar/filter options (not pictured) are robust enough for me to find what I'm looking for, and I'm usually just managing the information, rather than analyzing it.  Is this a good pattern for data tables with similar information -- that is, with text-heavy data that is searched rather than sorted?

EDIT: Looks like Mailchimp's styleguide calls them "slats" https://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/slats . Haven't seen that phrase in use, so still looking for answers. Answer below mentions that these are more like formatted lists than tables, so I'll look at those for answers too.

Comment: Updating with more examples I've found (more table-based than mailchimp's mini-report):
Pearson calls it "secondary rows" https://uxframework.pearson.com/c/tables/v1.1.0-beta.1
Tailwind UI calls it "multi-line content" https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/tables/wide

Answer (score 4):

This has been referred to as a **[list inlay pattern](https://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/list-inlay/)**, although the implication on mobile is that it expands, whereas your example is persistent:

From [Designing Interfaces](https://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/list-inlay/)

> A List Inlay shows an item’s details within the context of the list itself. The user can see the surrounding items, which might help in understanding and using the item contents.

I've also seen this nicknamed 'fat rows', where you have visible subrows of secondary data that is persistent, as per your example.

Comment: That's useful, thank you! I'll use this as a jumping off point to find more phrases.